# Generate a new Json specifying a selection of fields from another existent Json inside async/await

Tags: javascript, json, promise

in my Vue app I have this piece of code:

```
    async fetchCars() {
      try {
        let response = await fetch("https://cars.com/api/")
        let cars = await response.json()
        this.cars = cars
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
   }
```

{{ cars }} will return this:

```
{
  "owner": "",
  "place": ""
  "cars": [
    {
    "model": "",
    "make": "",
    "color": "",
    "features": [
    {
      "gear": "",
      "roof": "",
      "wheels": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

However I would like to specify the fields to keep (not the ones to delete), and have:

```
{
  "owner": "",
  "cars": [
    {
    "model": "",
    "make": "",
    "features": [
     {
      "gear": "",
      "roof": ""
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to play with .map() and Promise.all() but with no success.
Thanks

Comment: you are showing invalid json as input :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are more pretty ways, I am not sure, but I am using nested [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) here. You don't need `Promise.all` to map some values.

```js
const mapped = [{
  "owner": "",
  "place": "",
  "cars": [{
    "model": "",
    "make": "",
    "color": "",
    "features": [{
      "gear": "",
      "roof": "",
      "wheels": ""
    }]
  }]
}].map(({
  owner,
  cars
}) => ({
  owner,
  cars: cars.map(({
    model,
    make,
    features
  }) => ({
    model,
    make,
    features: features.map(({
      gear,
      roof
    }) => ({
      gear,
      roof
    }))
  }))
}))

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: whenever I try map() I get an empty {}. After the line let cars = await response.json() how should I .map() from there?

Comment: @Saro, yes once the cars are fetched and the response is converted via `.json()`, you should use the map on that array. Make sure it is actually inside what you think is inside with console.log maybe.